# How to add more claims to openid-configuration's claims_supported?

Tags: api, asp.net-core, oauth-2.0, openid-connect, adfs

I'm trying to request more user data such as `given_name` or `email` in my ADFS JWT token by adding `openid`
, `email` and `profile` scopes to the request:

```
https://example.com/adfs/oauth2/authorize/?client_id=8acf9328-1467-4d9f-ae69-8c2ed6e5d6ca&redirect_uri=https://localhost:4400/signin-oidc&response_type=code&scope=openid profile email...
```

```
.AddOpenIdConnect(options =>
{
    options.SignInScheme = "Cookies";
    options.Authority = config.AuthenticationOptions.Authority;
    options.RequireHttpsMetadata = true;
    options.ResponseType = OpenIdConnectResponseType.Code;
    options.UsePkce = false;
    options.Scope.Clear();
    options.Scope.Add("openid");
    options.Scope.Add("profile");
    options.Scope.Add("email");
    options.SaveTokens = true;
    options.MetadataAddress = config.AuthenticationOptions.Configuration;
    options.ClientId = config.AuthenticationOptions.ClientId;
});
```

But the response doesn't contain any other property except those that are listed in my `.well-known/openid-configuration's claims_supported`:

```
"claims_supported": [
"aud",
"iss",
"iat",
"exp",
"auth_time",
"nonce",
"at_hash",
"c_hash",
"sub",
"upn",
"unique_name",
"pwd_url",
"pwd_exp",
"mfa_auth_time",
"sid",
"nbf"
],
```

(`https://example.com/adfs/userinfo` only returns `sub`)

The question is how do I add more claims (`given_name`, `email` etc.) to the scopes that are already supported:

```
"scopes_supported": [
"logon_cert",
"user_impersonation",
"vpn_cert",
"winhello_cert",
"allatclaims",
"aza",
"openid",
"email",
"profile"
],
```

[Desired claims are already mapped in ADFS](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kfZjU.png)

I've tried to map additional claims to see if they'll appear in JWT, but they didn't. JWT contains a limited amount of claims.

Comment: mapping claims in ADFS is not enough, You'll need to configure your client application to request those claims. What Authorization server are you using ?

Comment: ADFS 2019. Or did you mean something different? @GopalZadafiya

Comment: The ID token might not contain all the claims, the client can also get claims from the UserInfo endpoint.  To reduce token size, the ID-token might not contain that many user-claims, and instead the client fetches them from the UserInfo endpoint.

Comment: @ToreNestenius As I said, /userinfo returns `sub` claim and nothing else, even though I request all the scopes.

Answer (score 0):

You should really have that information in the user profile. Or they won't appear in JWT.
[image]

Decode the Access Token or ID Token:

[image]